# Doctrine2 Many to Many fetch rows issue

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many, query-builder

I have a problem passing a value to Doctrine2 QueryBuilder in Symfony2.
I have two Entyties joined in unidirectional ManyToMany relationship:
Articles and Tags, and it works fine, but when I try to pass a value to the qb parameter it reads Error espetcted Literal got 'ORDER' or get nothing (but records exists).
The code:

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Bundle:Articles');
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->select('l,t')
        ->leftJoin('l.tags', 't')
        ->where('1=1')
        ->orderBy('l.titol', 'ASC');

if(isset($criteria['Titol']) && !empty($criteria['Titol']) &&
    strlen(trim($criteria['Titol']))){
        $qb->andWhere('l.titol like :titol')
           ->setParameter('titol','%'.$criteria['Titol'].'%');
}

if(isset($criteria['includeRecurs']) && 
    !empty($criteria['includeRecurs']) && 
    trim($criteria['includeRecurs']=='recurs')){
        $qb->andWhere('trim(l.urlMicroSite) !=\'\' and l.urlMicroSite is not null');
}

if(isset($criteria['tag']) && is_array($criteria['tag']) && count($criteria['tag'])){
    foreach($criteria['tag'] as $k=>$v){
        $qb->andWhere( 't.id=:'.$k)->setParameter($k,$criteria['tag'][$k]);
    }
}
```

The problem is in the last assignation, the other works:

```
$qb->andWhere( 't.id=:'.$k)->setParameter($k,$v);
```

if I set manually the variable $v eg: setParameter($k,3) or setParameter($k,'3') it works fine... but if I set the value $v=3 and then call the code, it don't get anything (and no error).
If I set directly the andWhere condition, eg andWhere('t.id='.$v) it reads Error especting Literal got 'ORDER', hardcoding the value it works again.
I'm shure the $v is correct (var_dump, echo, etc).
Any help will be apreciated (and sorry for my english)

Comment: You should first log the SQL statement and see what is passed to the SQL layer.

Comment: Hi Ocramius, here the sql log, I tryed three cases and the matter seems to be the repetition of the parameter in the t.id that I cannot understand.

Answer (score 0):

Well due to post space I need to post here:
case 1 query with original parameter, NO results:

```
 --no results (parameter $v)
    SELECT l0_.ISBN AS ISBN0, l0_.EAN AS EAN1, l0_.numeroPagines AS numeroPagines2,
    l0_.preuLlibre AS preuLlibre3, 
    l0_.format AS format4, 
    l0_.dataPublicacio AS dataPublicacio5, 
    l0_.titolOriginal AS titolOriginal6, 
    l0_.disenyCoberta AS disenyCoberta7,
    l0_.ilustrador AS ilustrador8, l0_.coleccio AS coleccio9, l0_.versioDe AS versioDe10,
    l0_.descripcioCurta AS descripcioCurta11, l0_.urlMicroSite AS urlMicroSite12,
    l0_.visibleInici AS visibleInici13, l0_.titol AS titol14, l0_.autor AS autor15,
    l0_.descripcio AS descripcio16, l0_.imatge AS imatge17, l0_.id AS id18,
    l0_.idUsuariCreacio AS idUsuariCreacio19, l0_.dataCreacio AS dataCreacio20,
    l0_.idUsuariModificacio AS idUsuariModificacio21, 
    l0_.dataModificacio AS dataModificacio22,
    l0_.userLock AS userLock23, 
    t1_.nomTag AS nomTag24, 
    t1_.tipusTag AS tipusTag25, 
    t1_.id AS id26, 
    t1_.idUsuariCreacio AS idUsuariCreacio27, 
    t1_.dataCreacio AS dataCreacio28, 
    t1_.idUsuariModificacio AS idUsuariModificacio29, 
    t1_.dataModificacio AS dataModificacio30,
    t1_.userLock AS userLock31 
    FROM Llibre l0_ LEFT JOIN llibre_tag l2_ 
        ON l0_.id = l2_.llibre_id 
    LEFT JOIN Tags t1_ 
        ON t1_.id = l2_.tag_id 
    WHERE 1 = 1 
        AND t1_.id = '3' 
        **AND t1_.id = ''** <-- empty duplicated parameter (but why duplicated??)
    ORDER BY l0_.titol ASC
```

Here the same query with the parameter $v=3 hardcoded

```
--1 result as expected (parameter $v)
    SELECT l0_.ISBN AS ISBN0, l0_.EAN AS EAN1, l0_.numeroPagines AS numeroPagines2,
    l0_.preuLlibre AS preuLlibre3, 
    l0_.format AS format4, 
    l0_.dataPublicacio AS dataPublicacio5, 
    l0_.titolOriginal AS titolOriginal6, 
    l0_.disenyCoberta AS disenyCoberta7,
    l0_.ilustrador AS ilustrador8, l0_.coleccio AS coleccio9, l0_.versioDe AS versioDe10,
    l0_.descripcioCurta AS descripcioCurta11, l0_.urlMicroSite AS urlMicroSite12,
    l0_.visibleInici AS visibleInici13, l0_.titol AS titol14, l0_.autor AS autor15,
    l0_.descripcio AS descripcio16, l0_.imatge AS imatge17, l0_.id AS id18,
    l0_.idUsuariCreacio AS idUsuariCreacio19, l0_.dataCreacio AS dataCreacio20,
    l0_.idUsuariModificacio AS idUsuariModificacio21, 
    l0_.dataModificacio AS dataModificacio22,
    l0_.userLock AS userLock23, 
    t1_.nomTag AS nomTag24, 
    t1_.tipusTag AS tipusTag25, 
    t1_.id AS id26, 
    t1_.idUsuariCreacio AS idUsuariCreacio27, 
    t1_.dataCreacio AS dataCreacio28, 
    t1_.idUsuariModificacio AS idUsuariModificacio29, 
    t1_.dataModificacio AS dataModificacio30,
    t1_.userLock AS userLock31 
    FROM Llibre l0_ LEFT JOIN llibre_tag l2_ 
        ON l0_.id = l2_.llibre_id 
    LEFT JOIN Tags t1_ 
        ON t1_.id = l2_.tag_id 
    WHERE 1 = 1 
        AND t1_.id = '3' 
        **AND t1_.id = '3'** 
    ORDER BY l0_.titol ASC
```

Finally the query with an other parameter that isn't duplicated..

```
--1 result as expected (parameter $v=4,$title="%quil%")
SELECT l0_.ISBN AS ISBN0, l0_.EAN AS EAN1, l0_.numeroPagines AS numeroPagines2,
l0_.preuLlibre AS preuLlibre3, 
l0_.format AS format4, 
l0_.dataPublicacio AS dataPublicacio5, 
l0_.titolOriginal AS titolOriginal6, 
l0_.disenyCoberta AS disenyCoberta7,
l0_.ilustrador AS ilustrador8, l0_.coleccio AS coleccio9, l0_.versioDe AS versioDe10,
l0_.descripcioCurta AS descripcioCurta11, l0_.urlMicroSite AS urlMicroSite12,
l0_.visibleInici AS visibleInici13, l0_.titol AS titol14, l0_.autor AS autor15,
l0_.descripcio AS descripcio16, l0_.imatge AS imatge17, l0_.id AS id18,
l0_.idUsuariCreacio AS idUsuariCreacio19, l0_.dataCreacio AS dataCreacio20,
l0_.idUsuariModificacio AS idUsuariModificacio21, 
l0_.dataModificacio AS dataModificacio22,
l0_.userLock AS userLock23, 
t1_.nomTag AS nomTag24, 
t1_.tipusTag AS tipusTag25, 
t1_.id AS id26, 
t1_.idUsuariCreacio AS idUsuariCreacio27, 
t1_.dataCreacio AS dataCreacio28, 
t1_.idUsuariModificacio AS idUsuariModificacio29, 
t1_.dataModificacio AS dataModificacio30,
t1_.userLock AS userLock31 
FROM Llibre l0_ LEFT JOIN llibre_tag l2_ 
    ON l0_.id = l2_.llibre_id 
LEFT JOIN Tags t1_ 
    ON t1_.id = l2_.tag_id 
WHERE 1 = 1 
    AND l0_.titol LIKE '%quil%' 
    AND t1_.id = '3' 
    **AND t1_.id = '3**' 
ORDER BY l0_.titol ASC
```

Comment: Well find my logical mistake!